# table valued function getting working days excluding weekend and holidays

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-function

actually the function does not work properly after many tests

for example I've tried`Select * from [dbo].[fn_GetLeaveDays] ('2020-09-24',1,'2020-09-25',1,1,1)`
and it should returns only 1 as friday is weekend but it returns 2

could you please assist to find whats wrong in the function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetLeaveDays] (@DateFrom datetime2,
                                    @CalendarFunction int,
                                    @DateTo AS datetime2,
                                    @AdjustMode bit,
                                    @AdjustWeekEnds bit,
                                    @AdjustHolidays bit)
RETURNS @tbl table (totaldays int)
AS
BEGIN

IF @DateFrom > @DateTo
BEGIN
    DECLARE @T datetime2 = @DateTo,
            @F datetime2 = @DateFrom;
    SELECT @DateFrom = @T,
           @DateTo = @F;
END;

DECLARE @Count AS int = 0,
        @Date AS datetime2 = @DateFrom;

WHILE @Date < @DateTo
BEGIN
    IF ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date) IN (6)
     AND @AdjustWeekEnds = 1)
     OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM [C3DCalendar].[dbo].[PRIMAVERA_CALENDAR_HOLIDAYS]
                WHERE holiday_date = @Date
                  AND calendar_key = @CalendarFunction
                  AND @AdjustHolidays = 1))
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Count = @Count + 1;
    END;

    SELECT @Date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date);
END;
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT (DATEDIFF(DAY, @DateFrom, @DateTo) - (@Count)) + @AdjustMode;
RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: The question presents `fn_GetLeaveDays` and tests against `fn_GetLeaveDays_scalar ` - are you doing the same?

Comment: yes they are the same, it was mistake

Comment: using SQL......

Comment: The easiest way to do calculations like this is using a calendar table. Add a column once by joining to your holiday table and the do a Cumulative Sum over 0/1, 1=workday, 1=weeekend/holiday etc. This results in a kind of "workday number" and your calculation is now based on two joins, start & end, and a simple end.day# - start.day#